# Google Trends API - data frequency

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-trends

I have gained access to the Google Trends API and tried downloading some trends data using the getting started guide's code:

```
start_date = ​'2010-01'
end_date = ​'2018-01'
response = service.getGraph(terms=​'apple'​,restrictions_startDate=start_date,restrictions_endDate=end_date).execute()
pprint.pprint(response)
```

This returns monthly data. Is there a way to get the data in daily frequency?

Answer (score 0):

`Google Trends API` Data frequency currently includes the Weekly and Monthly frequencies, country wise trend subscription

Currently Weekly is the shortest time accepted by the `Google Trends API` but in future might be available for daily time scale frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a shorter time period to get weekly or daily resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

`getGraph` returns results by week only. To get results by day, use `getTimelinesForHealth` instead and add the parameter `timelineResolution = 'day'`, as in:

```
response = service.getTimelinesForHealth(
    terms = ​'apple'​,
    time_startDate = 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    time_endDate = 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    timelineResolution = 'day'
).execute()
```

Note that `restrictions_startDate` and `restrictions_endDate` should be
changed to `time_startDate` and `time_endDate` respectively, and the time
is indicated in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.